# Execute C Macro Function At Compile Time

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, compile-time

Is it possible to run a c macro function at compile time.
for example writing something in a file each time code is compiled.

Comment: What is "macro function"?

Comment: If you mean actually calling executable code during compilation, and not just expanding macros in the source, then no...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Macro function like -> #define MAX(a, b) blah blah blah

Comment: This is macro. Not function. And yes. it is "executed" in compile time.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Specifically it's a "function-like macro", i.e., one that takes one or more arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes; No.

The macros *do* execute at compile time but there isn't much you can do directly with them other than mix text into the code.

Now, taking the [software tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020103669X) approach that unix pioneered (after all) you could conditionally generate output with `#warning` and then catch this with some script via a pipe.

Then that script could do stuff.

But, you probably wouldn't want to do that. Once you are running a script you could just have that script do whatever you want. Also, `#error` and `#warning` don't macro-expand the error or warning text, so using them for I/O is problematic.

This is obvious, I suppose, but how about using Ruby, Python, or the shell to script some macro processing?

Comment: Note that `#warning` is not defined by the C standard, though it's likely a majority of compilers support it.  GCC does, and therefore so does Clang; I believe MSVC does too; I expect others do too, but it is not standard.

Answer (score 2):

Macros in C are strictly a text substitution tool.  The output of the preprocessor is a preprocessed file.

So no, you can't do additional tasks like that from the preprocessor.

If you really want to perform certain tasks at compile time, that's what `make` is for.